# Javascript. Passing input variables throughout pages via AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

This is a Google suggestion-like script.

I rewrote the AJAX Call code by splitting it up into multiple functions and seems this is a better cross-browser/usability approach. Now I need to pass the input variable that I read from the input #search_text to a php file where I actually fetch the data from database.

For moment all I need is to pass search_text and display it with echo $_GET['search_text'];
Can someone help me?

Here is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*note xmlHttp needs to be a global variable. Because it is not it requires that function handleStateChange to pass the xmlHttp
    handleStateChange is written in such a way that is expects xmlHttp to be a global variable.*/
    function startRequest(getURL){
            var xmlHttp = false;
            xmlHttp = createXMLHttpRequest();
            //xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=handleStateChange;
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){handleStateChange(xmlHttp);}
            xmlHttp.open("GET", getURL ,true);
            xmlHttp.send();
    }

    function createXMLHttpRequest() {
        var _msxml_progid = [
        'Microsoft.XMLHTTP', 
        'MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0',
        'MSXML3.XMLHTTP',
        'MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0'
        ];
        //req is assiqning to xmlhttp through a self invoking function
        var xmlHttp = (function() {
        var req;
        try {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch( e ) {
        var len = _msxml_progid.length;
        while( len-- ) {
            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject(_msxml_progid[len]);
                break;
            } catch(e2) { }
        }
        } finally {
        return req;
        }
        }());

        return xmlHttp;
        }

    //handleStateChange is written in such a way that is expects xmlHttp to be a global variable. 
    function handleStateChange(xmlHttp){
            if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
                    if(xmlHttp.status == 200){
                            //alert(xmlHttp.status);
                            //alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
                            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
                    }
            }
    }

    function suggest() {

        startRequest("ajax-submit.php");
    }
    </script>



<body>
        <form action="" name="search" id="search">
        <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" onkeydown="suggest();" />
        </form>
        <div id="results" style="background:yellow"></div>
</body>
```

and the php file is:

```
<?php
echo 'Something';//'while typing it displays Something in result div
//echo $_GET['search_text'];
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: You've given a script and asked for help, but you haven't indicated what's actually wrong. FWIW, my advice to you is to throw all this away and pick any of jQuery/Prototype/YUI that already do this for you. You'll never build a car if you spend all your time reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're not actually passing in any data to the PHP script.  In this case, you need to stick the 'search_text' parameter on the end of the URL, since you're expecting it to be a GET request.

```
startRequest("ajax-submit.php");
```

should be

```
startRequest("ajax-submit.php?search_text="+document.search.search_text.value);
```

Comment: Do you think a POST request will automatically send data without explicit variables? I am very interested to find out. Thank you for the clue!

Comment: I think there is a mispelled character: ajax-submit.php?search_text="+document.search.search_text.value,      ? instead &. However it still won't take it. I tried to test it in the browser url input and it should write in real time, still no luck

Comment: A POST request will let you send data without adding variables to the URL, but you still need to send those values to the AJAX script and pass them as data to the URL.

Comment: Sorry about the typo, it's been fixed.  What happens (or doesn't happen) when you put the URL in the browser?  You should at least be getting a blank page with `Something` on it...

Answer (score 0):

this jQuery Solution is way easier and Cross-Browser compatible:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function(){

        $('#search_text').keydown(function(){     // Bind event to KeyDown

          var search_text = $(this).val();        // get value of input field

          $.ajax({                                // fire Ajax Request
            url: "ajax-submit.php?search_text=" + search_text,
            success: function(result){
              $("#results").html(result);         // on success show result.
            }
          });
        });

    });
    </script>


<body>
        <form action="" name="search" id="search">
        <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" />
        </form>
        <div id="results" style="background:yellow"></div>
</body>
```